# Python - How to Transpose Matrix from 3x2 to 2x3

Tags: python, matrix, multidimensional-array, transpose

```
A = [
    [1, 2],
    [4, 6],
    [3, 9]
]

print("\nHasil dari B= ")
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(2):
        B=2*A[i][j]
        print(B, end="  ")
     print("")   

output:
2  4
8  12
6  18
```

How to transpose from 3x2 to 2x3 matrix, from existing output results

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matrix Transpose in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937491/matrix-transpose-in-python)

Comment: in python : ```list(map(list, [*zip(*A)]))```

Comment: And see the answer there on using numpy; certainly for non-trivial use cases .

Answer (score 0):

For handling such arrays, consider using numpy. It provides all such operations for the matrix. Otherwise you would have to have a new array with the size of 2x3 and copy value by value.