# How do I create a numpy array using a function?

Tags: python, matrix, numpy, lambda

I am using `np.fromfunction` to create an array of a specific sized based on a function. It looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
test = [[1,0],[0,2]]
f = lambda i, j: sum(test[i])
matrix = np.fromfunction(f, (len(test), len(test)), dtype=int)
```

However, I receive the following error:

```
TypeError: only integer arrays with one element can be converted to an index
```

Comment: Just for reference: [Looking at numpy source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.7.0/numpy/core/numeric.py#L1611) `fromfunction` just creates `indices` array and passes it to user function. So `i` and `j` are `array`s, not `int`s.

Comment: @mg007 I believe the function will unbox those, however.

Comment: You can see how it performs that task in this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400739/what-does-mean-in-python

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The function needs to handle numpy arrays. An easy way to get this working is:

```
import numpy as np
test = [[1,0],[0,2]]
f = lambda i, j: sum(test[i])
matrix = np.fromfunction(np.vectorize(f), (len(test), len(test)), dtype=int)
```

`np.vectorize` returns a vectorized version of f, which will handle the arrays correctly.

Comment: passing the function through `np.vectorize` is _the_ trick documentation fails to point out, thank you so much

Comment: Excellent trick! It ought to be in the docs. I had similar problem with trivial scenario `f = lambda i, j: 3.14`  Running `np.fromfunction(f, (2, 6))` would simply give me a scalar 3.14 !  By contrast, `np.fromfunction(np.vectorize(f), (2, 6))` returns the expected 2x6 matrix whose entries are all 3.14