# get slice from multi-dimensions in python

Tags: python

```
LISTA=[["001", "TOM", "13800000001", "AAAA"],["002", "Jerry", "13800000002", "BBBB"]]
name=[]
for ID,NAME,HSNUMBER,ADDRESS in LISTA:
    name.append(NAME)

>>> name
['TOM', 'Jerry']
```

I feel it is not a simple way to get all the NAME in LISTA,how to revise it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is very simple way.

```
>>> LISTA=[["001", "TOM", "13800000001", "AAAA"],["002", "Jerry", "13800000002", "BBBB"]]
>>> name = zip(*LISTA)[1]
('TOM', 'Jerry')
```

### UPDATE

**what is the meaning of `*` here?**

In general

```
x = func(*[a, b, c])
```

is equivalent to

```
x = func(a, b, c)
```

So here

```
#zip(*LISTA)
zip(*[["001", "TOM", "13800000001", "AAAA"],["002", "Jerry", "13800000002", "BBBB"]])
```

is equivalent to

```
zip(["001", "TOM", "13800000001", "AAAA"],["002", "Jerry", "13800000002", "BBBB"])
```

Comment: what is the meaning of `*` here?

Comment: It means just passing each element of list as argument. Please see [What does * mean in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400739/what-does-mean-in-python) for more detail.

Comment: in python3 ,it is `list(zip(*LISTA))[1]`.

Comment: Ah I didn't know that. In python 2.7 it is `list(itertools.izip(*LISTA))[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

You know that the name will be the second element in the lists, so you can use list comprehension, like this

```
names = [item[1] for item in LISTA]
print names
# ['TOM', 'Jerry']
```