# How to send list of figures into Bokeh vplot()

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm building up a list of plots programatically in a Python list and I'd like to throw it at the `vplot` function instead of the `grid` I'm currently using. The documentation has the explicit enumeration of the children but I'm wondering if I can take a list of figure objects and receive them into vplot somehow much like how is done for the grid object.

```
channelPlots = []

for channel in myChannels :
    channelPlot = figure( width=1000, height=1000 , title=channel+ " Time Series" , x_axis_label = channel , y_axis_label = "TIME" )
    y           = sample.data['TIME' ]
    x           = sample.data[channel]
    channelPlot.scatter(x,y)
    channelPlots.append(channelPlot)

# With a grid it works  
#grid = GridPlot(children=[channelPlots], title="Time Series Channel Plots")

# with a vplot it breaks
grid = vplot( channelPlots )
save(grid)


Exception error is: expected an element of List(Instance(Widget)), got [[<bokeh.plotting.Figure object at 0x0000000009AA2128>, <bokeh.plotting.Figure object at 0x0000000006778CF8>, <bokeh.plotting.Figure object at 0
x0000000011894C50>, <bokeh.plotting.Figure object at 0x00000000118DE390>, <bokeh.plotting.Figure object at 0x00000000118DEF98>, <bokeh.plotting.Figure object at 0x00000000118F2668>, <bokeh.plotting.Figure object at
0x00000000118EE7B8>, <bokeh.plotting.Figure object at 0x00000000118EE630>]]
```

and attempting both of these below threw the same exception...

```
grid = vplot(children=channelPlots)
grid = vplot(children=[channelPlots])
Exception error is: Viewable object got multiple values for keyword argument 'children'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You either need to pass the list explicitly as the `children` parameter:

```
grid = vplot(children=channelPlots)
```

Or alternatively, `vplot` accepts the children as `*args`:

```
grid = vplot(*channelPlots)
```

Comment: The first method, which I also tried yesterday, threw an exception for me. I updated the Question to list that attempt too. The second one worked for me though. Solid!

Comment: did you try both of them at the same time as you seem to have done above? the `vplot(children=[channelPlots])` one will definitely throw the exception. `children` accepts a list, and `channelPlots` is already a list, so when you do  `vplot(children=[channelPlots])`  you are trying to set a list of lists, which is an error.

Comment: Oh, actually I just noticed the exception is different than I expected, I think you found a small bug. Can you file a GH issue about it?

Comment: I tried them one at a time, but both threw the same exception.  I'm using `>>> bokeh.__version__ '0.9.2'`. I just double checked again,...

`print(type(channelPlots))
grid = vplot(children=channelPlots)

<class 'list'>
Exception error is: Viewable object got multiple values for keyword argument 'children'`

Comment: Just submitted, _Bug in vplot/hplot children argument #2740_

Comment: Very cool, didn't realize this asterisk character was a formal operator in Python, [argument-unpacking operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400739/what-does-asterisk-mean-in-python/406488#406488)