# Turn a list into a tuple of arguments

Tags: python, list, arguments

Python `itertools.product()` takes coma separated 1D lists and returns a product. I have a list of divisors of a number in a form

```
l=[[1, a1**1,a1**2,..a1**b1],[1,a2**1,..a2**b2],..[1, an**1, an**2,..an**bn]]
```

When I pass it to itertools.product() as an argument I don't get the desired result. How can I feed this list of lists of integers to product()?

```
import itertools

print([list(x) for x in itertools.product([1,2,4],[1,3])]) 
#  [[1, 1], [1, 3], [2, 1], [2, 3], [4, 1], [4, 3]]  #desired

l1=[1,2,4],[1,3] #doesn't work
print([list(x) for x in itertools.product(l1)])
#[[[1, 2, 4]], [[1, 3]]]

l2=[[1,2,4],[1,3]] #doesn't work
print([list(x) for x in itertools.product(l2)])
#[[[1, 2, 4]], [[1, 3]]]
```

Comment: Please share the desired output of your input i.e. `l2=[[1,2,4],[1,3]`

Comment: Also, you want cartesian product of two lists? Because that is what `itertools.product()` does

Comment: I want to have a list of all divisors of `n` given the prime factors of n.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `*l2` within the `product()` as `*` unwraps the list. In this case, the value of `*[[1,2,4],[1,3]]` will be `[1,2,4],[1,3]`. Here's your code:

```
l2 = [[1,2,4],[1,3]] 
print([list(x) for x in itertools.product(*l2)])
# Output: [[1, 1], [1, 3], [2, 1], [2, 3], [4, 1], [4, 3]]
```

Please check: [What does asterisk mean in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400739/what-does-asterisk-mean-in-python). Also read regarding `*args` and `**kwargs`, you might find it useful. Check: [*args and **kwargs in python explained](https://pythontips.com/2013/08/04/args-and-kwargs-in-python-explained/)

Comment: What is this `*`? I want to read more about it. Worked like charm.

Comment: Check this: https://pythontips.com/2013/08/04/args-and-kwargs-in-python-explained/ Also adding with the answer for others looking for it

Comment: To be precise, you need to know: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400739/what-does-asterisk-mean-in-python

Comment: My appreciation and best wishes to your rep

Comment: @sixtytrees : Thank You :)