# Confused zip(*zip(x, y)) in Python3, can the * operator unzip an iterator?

Tags: python

The official Python3 Documents said:

> zip() in conjunction with the * operator can be used to unzip a **list**:

But also said, the zip() is "Make an **iterator** that aggregates elements from each of the iterables"

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [4, 5, 6]
zipped = zip(x, y)
list(zipped)

x2, y2 = zip(*zip(x, y))
```

I'm confused with the last line `zip(*zip(x, y))`, the `zip(x, y)` returns a iterable object, not a list. How can `*zip(x, y)` works!? How can `*upzip` an iterator!?

Comment: Why do you  think `*` cannot unpack an iterator? It may simply call `next()` until iterator is exhausted

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does asterisk \* mean in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400739/what-does-asterisk-mean-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

This is what happens in the last statement. The inner `zip`:

```
zip(x, y)
```

...results in an iterable over `([1,4], [2,5], [3,6])`. Then this:

```
zip(*zip(x, y))
```

translates to:

```
zip([1,4], [2,5], [3,6])
```

... because the asterisk consumes the iterable and spreads the values so they become individual arguments to the outer `zip` function.

That expression is than evaluated to an iterable over two values:

```
([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
```

... which needs to get assigned (unpacked) to two variables (`x2` and `y2` respectively), and so for that reason these two values are consumed from the iterable.