# What am I doing wrong in my query?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

So I have a table in my Customers.db file that looks like this:

[image]

I wanted to make a function which returns the "rows" which has the id equal to the user input. The Table is also called 'Customers and all the columns are type TEXT.

```
def run_query(db, query, args=NONE):
    con = sqlite3.connect(db)
    cur = con.cursor()
    if args is None:
        cur.execute(query)
    else:
        cur.execute(query, args)
    data = cur.fetchall()
    cur.close()
    con.close()
    return data


def get_info_by_id(db, ide):
    query = "SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE id = ?"
    return run_query(db, query, ide)
```

When I ran this in the shell like this

> > > get_info_by_id('Customers.db', '920')

I get the error "sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 3 supplied."

Comment: Add a sql tag to this question perhaps?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `args` argument of `cur.execute` needs to be an iterable so that they can be bound to multiple placeholders (`?`) if necessary. Therefore you should always be passing a list or tuple.

```
get_info_by_id('Customers.db', ['920'])
```

When you pass a string it gets treated as an iterable of single-character strings, hence it says there were 3 bindings (3 characters in `'920'`).

Comment: May I ask, why do I need the square bracket?

Comment: @Jun edited the answer.

Comment: I see! Thanks, I think I should read the books more carefully!

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your `run_query` function as:

```
def run_query(db, query, *args):
    #                     ^ *args here for variable number of arguments
    #                        It will read additional arguments as tuples
    ..
    cur.execute(query, args)   # No need of if-else now
    ..                         # It expects arguments to be in tuple format
```

For more information related to `*args`, take a look at: [What does asterisk * mean in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400739/what-does-asterisk-mean-in-python)