# What does asterix * means in Python

Tags: python

I've the following code in python:

`P = [0] * (6)`

What am I doing here? Am I multiplying an array and a number? What is the result?

I saw this topic:
[What does asterisk * mean in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400739/what-does-asterisk-mean-in-python)

But I guess it's not related.

Comment: why dont you just run it?

Comment: Will be the same as `p = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`, please be aware when doing `p = [[]] * 6`

Comment: Obviously there are some programmers who fell into an empty cauldron when they were young.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operators in Python are magic.  They invoke special methods depending on the class of the operand.  In this case a special method called `__mul__` is called from the `list` class, since a list object is on the left-side.

In the case of a list, the list is repeated by the number of times given on the right (the parentheses are meaningless in this case).  Tuple and string (`str`) objects can be multiplied in a similar way.

If you want to see what the special methods are, and their corresponding operators, see [the `operator` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/operator.html).

By the way, you use the term *array*, which is understandable coming from other languages.  However `[0]` does not create an array, but a `list` object.  That might sound like semantics, but arrays do exist in python, but they have a specialised use.  There is an [array module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) in the standard library, and the `numpy` module also has arrays, see [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.creation.html).  For everyday use though, `list` is the norm.

Answer (score 1):

if you run the code `[0] * (6)` you get `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`. Similarly, if you run `[1,2,3] * (6)` you get `[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]`. So the asterisk is repeating/*multiplying* the list.

Answer (score 0):

You're making, and concatenating, six copies of the list. I.e. `[0] * 6 == [0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0]`

Comment: ... and concatenating them.

Comment: Also be aware that the result contains shallow copies!

Answer (score -2):

Snarky answer. Sorry but I cant help myself... this would have been so much less work then posting here!!!!

Heres a screencaputre of me finding the answer by typing 15 characters.

```
[temp548@compute-0-96 CUDA]$ python
Python 2.4.3 (#1, Sep 21 2011, 19:55:41)
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-51)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> [0] * 6
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>>
```