# finding subsets of a set in python

Tags: python, set, tuples, subset

I have a tuple.`a = ('a1','a2','a3')`.
I want to find all the subsets of it except the null set. My question is: 'is there any built-in function for doing it?'. It should return ('a1'),('a2'),('a3'),('a1','a2'),('a2','a3'),('a3','a1').

Comment: what you are trying to do is find whats known as the power set (without the empty set) use that in google, and you will find the answer

Answer (score 4):

You can use `itertools.combinations` and `itertools.chain`

```
In [13]: from itertools import combinations, chain

In [14]: a = ('a1','a2','a3')

In [15]: list(chain(*(combinations(a, i) for i in xrange(1, len(a)))))
Out[15]: [('a1',), ('a2',), ('a3',), ('a1', 'a2'), ('a1', 'a3'), ('a2', 'a3')]
```

Comment: Great work combining `combinations` and `chain`. Demonstrates the power of itertools module.

Comment: what is the use of *?

Comment: Why not `chain.from_iterable`, so you can avoid unpacking the generator expression.

Comment: @MihirShanvir The * in this case is being used to unpack the iterable. [More information here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400739/what-does-asterisk-mean-in-python)

Comment: @MosesKoledoye, because I con't quite remember that syntax, I think `chain.from_iterable` is preferred, but since @dawg already uses it in his answer, I am going to leave mine the way it is.

Answer (score 4):

There is a [recipe](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) for [power sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) in itertools:

```
def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))
```

With your example:

```
>>> list(it.chain.from_iterable(it.combinations(a, r) for r in range(1, len(a)+1)))
[('a1',), ('a2',), ('a3',), ('a1', 'a2'), ('a1', 'a3'), ('a2', 'a3'), ('a1', 'a2', 'a3')]
```