# Python: Improved set notation?

Tags: python, set

In a tutorial I've read that sets can since Python 2.6 be defined like this:

```
a_set = {"Members", "of", "set"}
```

But let's say I want to achieve `a_set = set("Letters")` with that notation. `a_set = {"Letters"}` does not render the same output when printed:

```
>>> set1 = set("Letters")
>>> set2 = {"Letters"}
>>> print(set1, set2)
{'L', 'r', 't', 'e', 's'} {'Letters'}
```

Is the tutorial wrong? What is going on here? If `set2` is not a set, what is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are fundamentally confusing literal notation with a constructor function. The constructor functions for all the built-in containers take *iterables* and populate the container with the elements of the iterable. A container literal does not work this way, and isn't designed to work this way. Note, this is how it works with every built-in container type that supports literal notation:

```
>>> list('letters')
['l', 'e', 't', 't', 'e', 'r', 's']
>>> ['letters']
['letters']
>>>
```

So this shouldn't be surprising.

Answer (score 3):

The first variable `set1` creates a new `set` from the sequence of letters in the single string `"Letters"`.

The second variable `set2` creats a `set` with a single `str` object. It does not iterate over the individual letters to make a set.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to achieve `set1`by using the `{}`-notation?

Comment: @Sandi Not really. unless yous want to hack the CPython source code. Is there a reason you can't use `set`?

Comment: `{*'letters'}`  works on Python 3.6. Didn't try it on 2.x though.

Comment: No reason, I'm just curious. Thanks ayhan! What's the logic behind that working? What does asterisk no?

Comment: @Sandi It unpacks an iterable. Assume you have a list `a = ['x', 'y']` Normally, if you call a function with `func(a)`  the list is passed as the input. But if you do `func(*a)` it works like you did `func('x', 'y')`  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400739/what-does-asterisk-mean-in-python) are more details.

Answer (score 2):

Because in the first set you're passing an iterable. Pass it in a list like this and it will give you what you want.

```
In [148]: set(["Letters"])
Out[148]: {'Letters'}
```