# How do I extract the text part from <class 'generator'> part of an HTML tag while using a web-crawler

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import operator
from collections 
import Counter

def start(url):
  wordlist=[]
  source_code=requests.get(url).text
  soup=BeautifulSoup(source_code,'html.parser')
  for each_text in soup.findAll('div',{'class':'entry-content'}):
    content=each_text.strings
    words=content.lower().split()
    for each_word in words:
        wordlist.append(each_word)
    clean_wordlist(wordlist)

def clean_wordlist(wordlist):
  clean_list=[]
  for word in wordlist:
    symbols='!@#$%^&*()_-+={[}]|\;:"<>?/.,'
    for i in range (0,len(symbols)):
        word=word.replace(symbols[i],'')
    if len(word)>0:
        clean_list.append(word)
create_dictionary(clean_list)

def create_dictionary(clean_list):
  word_count={}
  for word in clean_list:
    if word in word_count:
        word_count[word]+=1
    else:
        word_count[word]=1
  for key,value in sorted(word_count.items(),key=operator.itemgetter(1)):
    print ("%s : %s " % (key,value))
  c=Counter(word_count)
  top=c.most_common(3)
  print(top)

 start("https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/programming-language-choose/")</code>
```

The following program gives the error "Attribute Error": "Generator" object has no attribute .lower(). 
I printed out the type of each_text.strings was returning which printed [class 'generator'] but now how do I move forward and get the text part from the given link

Comment: As documented, `.strings` returns a generator object. You'll have to iterate over it somehow to get the contents

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a generator object we just use `.text` or if we really wanted to use `.strings` you could then do unpacking (i.e. `print(*stingsobject)`)

As you can tell we use the asterisk before the object to unpack it, I'll not go into details but you can find more about it [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400739/what-does-asterisk-mean-in-python)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import operator
from collections import Counter


def start(url):
  wordlist = []
  source_code = requests.get(url).text
  soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code, 'html.parser')
  for each_text in soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'entry-content'}):
    content = each_text.text
    words = content.lower().split()
    for each_word in words:
        wordlist.append(each_word)
    clean_wordlist(wordlist)


def clean_wordlist(wordlist):
  clean_list = []
  for word in wordlist:
    symbols = '!@#$%^&*()_-+={[}]|\;:"<>?/.,'
    for i in range(0, len(symbols)):
        word = word.replace(symbols[i], '')
    if len(word) > 0:
        clean_list.append(word)
  create_dictionary(clean_list)


def create_dictionary(clean_list):
  word_count = {}
  for word in clean_list:
    if word in word_count:
        word_count[word] += 1
    else:
        word_count[word] = 1
  for key, value in sorted(word_count.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1)):
    print("%s : %s " % (key, value))
  c = Counter(word_count)
  top = c.most_common(3)
  print(top)

start("https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/programming-language-choose/")
```

Comment: Thanks a ton!! Your answer worked pitch perfect ! ;)