# How you pass a queryset in a Django ManyToManyField. Error: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'QuerySet'

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

**Intro:** Lets say I have a Feeds model which has a user and followers. When a user writes a post. All his followers get a feed on their homepage that the person they are following wrote a post.

```
class Feed(models.Model):
    being_followed = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, related_name="feeds_for_followers")
    follower = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name="homepage_feeds")        
    being_followed_post = models.ForeignKey(Post, blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**My issue:** Now if you see the post_create view below. The user is request.user the post is the post. However I am adding followers with the code

```
users_followers = post_user.followers.all()
for follower in users_followers: 
    feed.follower.add(follower)
```

which is very inefficient. Is there a way I can add the entire queryset users_followers to the followers ManytoManyField

I tried

```
followers = user.followers.all()
feed.follower.add(followers)
```

I get the below error

> int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'QuerySet'

Comment: I suggest you look into this project https://stream-framework.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: @OchuiPrincewill thanks for the link. I am reading through them,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
users_followers = post_user.followers.all()
feed.follower.add(*users_followers)
```

Comment: what does the * do

Comment: Its well explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400739/what-does-asterisk-mean-in-python :)

Comment: awesome, thanks that worked can choose the answer correct in 8 mins. Thanks again

Comment: Just doing more research on this. I am going to use Zappa to do asynchronously do this. But according to you, this would be the fastest way correct?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea regarding Zappa.