# Count number of string in the input function

Tags: python

The user provides an undefined number of strings as the input; we have to count number of strings the user provided.

I tried :

```py
    def count(terms*): # Example count('IloveU','Iwantyou','No')
        count = 0
        for term in terms:
            count += 1
        print (count)
```

Thank you

Comment: And what did it give you?

Comment: What is the value of `word` in your function?

Comment: The shown code will show an error because of different letter case: "Terms" <-> "terms" and a syntax error because of the asterisk in wrong position.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Thank you correcter that part.

Comment: @TaylorReece Updated the post.

Comment: @MichaelButscher  "terms" and a syntax error because of the asterisk in wrong position"" Can you please direct me to reference.

Comment: There is no such thing as asterisk after a variable name. It comes before https://stackoverflow.com/a/400823/8556199

Comment: @ProtimaRaniPaul Lets say this ('iloveU, Iwantyou, No'), what the you want as your function output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost there:
Asterix has to be in front of the params not at the end.

```
def count(*terms): # Example count('IloveU','Iwantyou','No')
      count = 0
      for term in terms:
          count += 1
      print (count)
```