# Pick evens using *args in Python

Tags: python, tuples, args

[image]

Hello, I'm a brand new beginner in Python, I'm taking the Udemy course and I got stuck at this question. Can you guys help me and please explain to me my mistake and the solutions? Please make the explanation as simple as possible because like I said, I'm brand new.
Thank you so much

Comment: The instructions say that your function should return a list. It shouldn't print anything by itself.

Comment: Please post your code as plain text, not an image.

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ...
[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: @Sushanth What if an even value is at an **even** position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*` will pack and unpack the list. In your case, you combines them to a tuple. More info - [What does asterisk * mean in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400739/what-does-asterisk-mean-in-python)

You just need to loop through them.

```
def myFunc(*args):
    return [i for i in args if i % 2 ==0]

print(myFunc(5,6,7,8))
```

Output:

```
[6,8]
```