# What does the *, in *zip, and *D.items() doing?

Tags: python, matplotlib

- How are `*zip` and `*D.items()` working in the following code?
- What does `*` operator do?

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

D = {u'Label1':26, u'Label2': 17, u'Label3':30}
plt.bar(*zip(*D.items()))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

### The asterisk operator as it relates to your code:

- An [iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable) is something that can be iterated though
- `*` unpacks an iterable
- `D.items()` creates a `dict_items` object, a `list` of `tuples`. See [`.items()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) and [dictionary view objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views)

  - `dict_items([('Label1', 26), ('Label2', 17), ('Label3', 30)])`
- The `*` in `zip(*D.items())`, unpacks the `dict_times` object, and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip), aggregates elements from each of the iterables.

  - `('Label1', 'Label2', 'Label3')`
  - `(26, 17, 30)`
  - [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) creates a [generator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator) (another iterable), like `<zip at 0x1c9f2248e00>`, which is an iterable of tuples.
- The `*` in `*zip` unpacks the generator, so the plot API has access to the two `tuples`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

D = {u'Label1':26, u'Label2': 17, u'Label3':30}
plt.bar(*zip(*D.items()))
```

[image]

### The asterisk operator in broader terms:

- [PEP 448 - Additional Unpacking Generalizations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/)
- [Real Python: Python args and kwargs: Demystified](https://realpython.com/python-kwargs-and-args/)
- [SO: What does asterisk * mean in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400739/)
- [Trey Hunner: Asterisks in Python: what they are and how to use them](https://treyhunner.com/2018/10/asterisks-in-python-what-they-are-and-how-to-use-them/)

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add to @TrentonMcKinney's answer some examples of how unpacking with `*` works:

```py
>>> l = [1, 2, 3]
>>> print(l)  # == print([1, 2, 3])
[1, 2, 3]
>>> print(*l)  # == print(1, 2, 3)
1 2 3
```

Basically `print(l)` was converted to `print([1, 2, 3])` and then the output was the list itself `[1, 2, 3]`.
On the other hand, `print(*l)` was converted to `print(1, 2, 3)`, this is, the list was unpacked an each element was passed as a separate argument to print, so the output was `1 2 3`.

So in your example, the inner `*` is unpacking each of the items tuples (`('Label1', 26)`, `('Label2', 17)` and `('Label3', 30)`) and passing them as a separate arguments to `zip` (`zip(('Label1', 26), ('Label2', 17), ('Label3', 30))`). That returns another list-like object equivalent to trasposing those sequences, this is, groups all the first elements of every iterable together, the second elements together, ... (`[('Label1', 'Label2', 'Label3'), (26, 17, 30)]`). The outter `*` unpacks them out of the list-like object to pass each tuple to the `plt.bar` function(`plt.bar(('Label1', 'Label2', 'Label3'), (26, 17, 30))`).

Similar to `*` to unpack sequences, there is a `**` that is used to unpack mappings into keyword arguments. `f(**{'a': 1, 'b': 2})` is the same as `f(a=1, b=2)`.