# TypeError while using *args in Python

Tags: python, tuples, typeerror, args, multiple-arguments

I'm getting a TypeError while using a tuple in a multiple arguments function. Here's my code:

```
def add(*args):
    result = 0
    for x in args:
        result = result + x
    return result

items = 5, 7, 4, 12
total = add(items)
print(total)
```

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\functions.py", line 9, in <module>
    total = add(items)
  File "e:\functions.py", line 4, in add
    result = result + x
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple'
```

I'm not getting any error if I directly enter the arguments instead of using a variable:

```
total = add(5, 7, 4, 12)
```

I've coded in Java and I just started using Python and I can't figure out why this is happening.

Comment: You are passing the single argument `items` (a tuple) to `add`, meaning that `args` is: `[(5, 7, 4, 12)]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does asterisk \* mean in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400739/what-does-asterisk-mean-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're passing the tuple `items` as a single argument to `add`, which is written to expect an arbitrary number of individual numeric arguments rather than a single iterable argument (that's what the `*args` syntax does -- it takes an artitrary number of arguments and converts them to an iterable inside the function).

The `TypeError` is happening because your `for x in args` is getting the value of `items` as its first value of `x` (since it's the first argument), and so your function is trying to do the operation `0 + (5, 7, 4, 12)`, which is not valid because you can't add an `int` to a `tuple` (which is why the error message says that).

To pass the individual items as individual args, do:

```
total = add(5, 7, 4, 12)
```

or unpack the tuple by mirroring the `*` syntax in the caller, like this:

```
total = add(*items)
```

Note that Python has a builtin function called `sum` that will do exactly what you want to do with your tuple:

```
total = sum(items)
```

You could get the same behavior from your `add` function by removing the `*` from the `*args` in your function definition.

Comment: Beat me to it. the unpacking of `items` should do the trick for the OP.

Answer (score 2):

When you do this.

```
items = 5, 7, 4, 12 #tuple & it looks like this (5,7,4,12)
total = add(items)
```

You pass your `items` variable to your `add` function & in general it would look like this.

```
total = add((5,7,4,12))#Not like this add(5,7,4,12)
```

Well...this is correct there is nothing wrong with it but base on your objective this is not the right way. Learn more about [*args](https://realpython.com/python-kwargs-and-args/) here.

This is what you are expecting to do & you can do this by `unpacking` as what the other answer suggests.

```
add(5,7,4,12)
```

Cause what you did is you passed the whole tuple so your `args` parameter would look like this `((5,7,4,12))` & when you do a for loop you are `iterating` the tuple (which is the **args**) object's value which is this `(5,7,4,12)` & then adding it to an `int` which is clearly an error as stated.

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def add(*args):
    result = 0
    for x in args:
        result = result + x
    return result

items = 5, 7, 4, 12
total = add(*items)
print(total)
```

just add a random * in `total = add(*items)`

result:

```
28
```

[What does ** (double star/asterisk) and * (star/asterisk) do for parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters)

[What does asterisk * mean in Python? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400739/what-does-asterisk-mean-in-python/400753#400753)