# Converting One Column (Fixed-Field-Width) Dataframe to Multicolumn Dataframe (Databricks, pyspark )

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a one column dataframe I ingested from a text file. So from this:

```
oneColDF = (spark.read
.format("text")        
.load(file_path))

display(oneColDF)
```

, leading to this df:

[image]

with a hundred or so rows. There is no dependable delimiter in this format (for instance, a space won't work because some fields have spaces within), however, the columns are fixed-width, so i know column name and width for each field (all fields are strings). I know this because I was provided with dictionary:

```
fixed_width_column_defs = {
  "submitted_at": (1, 15),
  "order_id": (16, 40),
  "customer_id": (56, 40),
  "sales_rep_id": (96, 40),
  "sales_rep_ssn": (136, 15),
  "sales_rep_first_name": (151, 15),
  "sales_rep_last_name": (166, 15),
  "sales_rep_address": (181, 40),
  "sales_rep_city": (221, 20),
  "sales_rep_state": (241, 2),
  "sales_rep_zip": (243, 5),
  "shipping_address_attention": (248, 30),
  "shipping_address_address": (278, 40),
  "shipping_address_city": (318, 20),
  "shipping_address_state": (338, 2),
  "shipping_address_zip": (340, 5),
  "product_id": (345, 40),
  "product_quantity": (385, 5),
  "product_sold_price": (390, 20)
}
```

So I can add empty columns like this:

```
multiColDF= oneColDF.withColumn('submitted_at',     
lit(None).cast(StringType())).withColumn('order_id', lit(None).cast(StringType())).withColumn('customer_id', lit(None).cast(StringType())).withColumn('sales_rep_id', lit(None).cast(StringType())).withColumn('sales_rep_ssn', lit(None).cast(StringType())).withColumn('sales_rep_first_name', lit(None).cast(StringType())).withColumn('sales_rep_last_name', lit(None).cast(StringType())).withColumn('sales_rep_address', lit(None).cast(StringType())).withColumn('sales_rep_city', lit(None).cast(StringType())).withColumn('sales_rep_state', lit(None).cast(StringType())).withColumn('sales_rep_zip', lit(None).cast(StringType())).withColumn('shipping_address_attention', lit(None).cast(StringType())).withColumn('shipping_address_address', lit(None).cast(StringType())).withColumn('shipping_address_city', lit(None).cast(StringType())).withColumn('shipping_address_state', lit(None).cast(StringType())).withColumn('shipping_address_zip', lit(None).cast(StringType())).withColumn('product_id', lit(None).cast(StringType())).withColumn('product_quantity', lit(None).cast(StringType())).withColumn('product_sold_price', lit(None).cast(StringType()))
```

, so now the dataframe has all the columns:

[image]

So I am trying to figure out how to loop through the dataframe to update all the columns with the appropriate data from the value column.

```
for row in multiColDF.rdd.collect():
   addTheDatafromValColToEachCol()
```

I am stuck at this point. I would be grateful for any ideas, either building on what i have done or perhaps a simpler solution. Thank you.

Comment: Suggest this might be renamed "access fixed field data file with spark sql". Old timers will understand that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to add the columns before, you can do this dynamically using substring and looping through the dictionary using select:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
out = df.select("value",*[F.substring("value",*v).alias(k) 
                     for k,v in fixed_width_column_defs.items()])
```

Comment: thank you! That did the trick. I am trying to understand the "*v"?

Comment: @TimothyClotworthy substring takes 3 parameters, 1: col , 2: position 3: length , we have the col, but not the other 2, hence we splat the values in v which is a tuple to populate the param 2 and param 3, try printing `[*(2,3)]`, you will see that the tuple has been unpacked to the container which is a list here.  that might help :)

Comment: sorry, from the context of the code above, how do I print out the [*(2,3)]?

Comment: @TimothyClotworthy sorry , I mean print it independently to understand like: `print([*(2,3)])` or even `print(*(2,3))` to see the unpacking of a tuple using a `*` . More details here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400739/what-does-asterisk-mean-in-python

Comment: hmm, so then I am confused on what I presume is another unpacking (this: *[F.substring("value",*v).alias(k) 
                     for k,v in fixed_width_column_defs.items()])?  Since it has asterisk in front of a fairly complex expression... Thanks!

Comment: @TimothyClotworthy that is for the select expression which requires individual columns, hence we unpack the list

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235950/discussion-between-timothy-clotworthy-and-anky).